# Flexbox space-evenly selector for gaps of element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

Hi i have a navbar created by flex box. Items are space-evenly. I need fill gaps around element with same blue color. And also after hover color will change so i need to select both li elements and gaps is there any way how to select them?.

```css
#menu{
   display: flex;
   margin-top: 0;
   padding: 0;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#menu li {
   height: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
   background:rgba(5, 151, 242, 1);
}

#menu li a{
   color:white;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   line-height: 6.5;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="page.php">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="page.php">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="page.php">Longer Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="page.php">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are thinking to complex. you don't need the `justify-content: space-evenly;`, but you need to let the li-elements grow with: `flex-grow: 1;`

Also you don't need to use `rgba`, if you don't use transparency you can use `rgb`

```css
#menu{
   display: flex;
   margin-top: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
   height: 100%;
   list-style-type: none;
   background:rgb(5, 151, 242);
   flex-grow: 1;
   text-align: center;
}

#menu li:hover {
   background:rgba(155, 5, 242);
}

#menu li a{
   color:white;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   line-height: 6.5;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="page.php">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="page.php">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="page.php">Longer Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="page.php">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

I made the whole block clickable as requested additionally. This is done by adding `display: block;` to the `a`-elements. A link is normally an inline-element, so this switches it to behave like a block element witch listens to the width/height settings already present in the question.

Comment: Thank you. Can i ask one more question to simple solution how to make whole li item clickcable? Yeah i think complex cause this is what it looks like when javascript developer doing css. :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `justify-content: space-evenly`, you can use `flex: 1` for each `<li>`. You can center the text using `text-align: center`.
Then, you create your hover effect for each item.

```css
#menu{
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  background:rgba(5, 151, 242, 1);
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#menu li a {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 6.5;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu li:hover {
  background: rgba(5, 151, 242, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="page.php">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="page.php">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="page.php">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="page.php">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```